# SQL SELECT DISTINCT Subquery Error: 1241

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, union, mysql-error-1241

I am working on a long query that includes a SELECT DISTINCT and subquery. It is partially working, but not when put together. I am getting a Error: 1241 - Operand should contain 1 column(s) and I cannot see why. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT p.projId, pc.company, s.staffId, s.fName, s.lName
    FROM projects AS p
    INNER JOIN projCorp AS pc ON p.projId = pc.projId
    INNER JOIN projStaff AS ps ON p.projId = ps.projId
    INNER JOIN staff AS s ON ps.staffId = s.StaffId
    WHERE p.projId = '9' AND s.company = pc.company
UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT p.projId, pc.company, "NA", "NA", "NA"
    FROM projects AS p
    INNER JOIN projCorp AS pc ON p.projId = pc.projId
    INNER JOIN projStaff AS ps ON p.projId = ps.projId
    WHERE p.projId = '9' AND pc.company NOT IN (SELECT p.projId, pc.company, s.staffId, s.fName, s.lName
        FROM projects AS p
        INNER JOIN projCorp AS pc ON p.projId = pc.projId
        INNER JOIN projStaff AS ps ON p.projId = ps.projId
        INNER JOIN staff AS s ON ps.staffId = s.StaffId
        WHERE p.projId = '9' AND s.company = pc.company);
```

Without the NOT IN subquery, I am getting this result:

[image: result without NOT IN subquery]

The reason for the NOT IN subquery is to get rid of the third duplicate entry that doesn't have a staff member associated. The result should just have the first two entries from the picture result field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Snip:

```
... WHERE p.projId = '9' AND pc.company NOT IN (
        SELECT p.projId, pc.company, s.staffId, s.fName, s.lName
        FROM projects AS p ....
    )
```

You're trying to select when `company not in` but there are specifying more than one selected row from within your `not in` query.  Just select `company`:

```
... WHERE p.projId = '9' AND pc.company NOT IN (
        SELECT pc.company
        FROM projects AS p ....
    )
```

Comment: Ah, indeed.  Guess I was just looking at the error, not the actual solution to the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to keep all the rows for a given projects, use a `left join`:

```
SELECT p.projId, pc.company, s.staffId, s.fName, s.lName
FROM projects p LEFT JOIN
     projCorp pc
     ON p.projId = pc.projId LEFT JOIN
     projStaff ps
     ON p.projId = ps.projId LEFT JOIN
     staff s
     ON ps.staffId = s.StaffId AND s.company = pc.company
WHERE p.projId = '9';
```

This seems more sensible than a complicated `union` query.  You can use `coalesce()` to convert the `NULL` values to `'NA'`, if that really is desirable.

I am a little confused on which table should go first -- but I'm thinking it is all companies as opposed to all projects.  If so, this is the `FROM` clause with no `WHERE`:

```
FROM projCorp pc LEFT JOIN
     projects p   
     ON p.projId = pc.projId AND p.projId = '9' LEFT JOIN
     projStaff ps
     ON p.projId = ps.projId LEFT JOIN
     staff s
     ON ps.staffId = s.StaffId AND s.company = pc.company;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your IN list should contain values from one column, pc.company. But your IN list contains values from multiple columns.